# Docker-compose - ERROR: no container found after directory change

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use to work on my host on a given directory.

```
dev_3/
     docker-compose-dev.yml
```

and my `docker-compose-dev.yml` had a service called 'web' in it, whose container would be called 'web_1', when up'd.

```
web (service) ---> web_1 (container)
```

---

Then I changed my directory path, but keeping the same directory name, 'dev_3'.

When I rebuilt all my images from the same file, docker renamed containers to 'web_2', 'client_2' and so on.

But now If I run this command:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml exec web python manage.py recreate_db
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: No container found for web_1
```

which does not exist anymore...so docker is still pointing to a ghost container.

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use brute force to solve the issue, with this command:

```
 docker container stop $(docker container ls -a -q) && docker system prune -a -f --volumes
```

And then all started working again, with new built images and fresh containers.